# Python freezes running exe file

Tags: python, cygwin

I'm doing a simple python gui and on button click it will run a simple command:

```
os.system("C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe")
```

When I look in the console it ran correctly and but my guy freezes and is not responding.
If I run the the command in the console without python it works perfectly and I start cygwin terminal.

If you know what is cygwin is there a better way to start it in the same terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system` blocks the current thread, you can use `os.popen` in order to do that in another thread, and it also gives you few methods to detach/read/write etc' that process.
for example,

```py
import os
a = os.popen("python -c 'while True: print(1)'")
```

will create a new process that will be terminated as soon as you terminate your script.
you can do

```py
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

for example, and it will block the thread as `os.system` does.
you can `a.detach()` it whenever you want to terminate the process.

However, `os.system`

```py
import os
os.system("python -c 'while True: print(1)'")
```

it will output the 1s forever until you terminate the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `Popen` in package `subprocess`. It has many possible arguments that allow you to pipe input to and/or pipe output from the program you are running. But if you just want to execute `bash.exe` while allowing your original Python program to continue running and eventually wait for the completion of `bash.exe`, then:

```python
import subprocess

# pass a list of command-line arguments:
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe"])

... # continue executing

# wait for the subprocess (bash.exe) to end:
exit_code = p.wait()
```